# Get the last row from 2 column then enter data into 1 of the column

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I did a search before posting this question. The results that I found are only finding the last row of 1 column, I would like to find the last row of 2 columns then enter the data accordingly. Hope you guys could help. Thanks! :)

```
If optMemberName.Value = True Then
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        Range("A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row) = txtMemberName.Text
    End With
ElseIf optMemberID.Value = True Then
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        Range("B" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row) = txtMemberID.Text
    End With
End If
```

This is the output now

[image]

This is how the userform looks like

[image]

This is the output that I want

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were pretty close to the solution. ;) Try this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim rA As Long, rB As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long
    rA = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row ' returns last row of first column
    rB = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row ' returns last row of second column
    lastRow = IIf(rA > rB, rA + 1, rB + 1) ' returns maximum of rA and rA plus one
    If optMemberName.Value = True Then
        Cells(lastRow, 1) = txtMemberName.Text
    ElseIf optMemberID.Value = True Then
        Cells(lastRow, 2) = txtMemberID.Text
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering my question, I tried your codes. But I have this `Run-time error '424'` `Object required` at this line `rA = Cells(Row.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` then I try adding `rA = Sheet1.Cells(Row.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` but I still have the same error.

Comment: `rA = Cells(Row.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` is wrong. It has to be `rA = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row`.  You have forgotten the **s**.

Comment: Oh. Haha yes, it works already :) Thanks so much! :) But is there other way of doing this? Not using `Cells` but `Range`?